# Ubuntu Share not working on Windows

Tags: 16.04, samba, lts

I'm a newbie, so pardon my ignorance. I have linux shares that work. e.g. `/home/ian/Documents`.  I can connect from my Windows PC and I can copy files from it.

I just mounted an extra hard drive on linux and it appears as `/media/ian/UbuntuD` but I can't connect to this from my Windows PC.  I have checked the permissions and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  From the Windows PC, it seems to connect, but then reports "Access is denied"

When I check on the Ubuntu terminal, it appears that the the User "nobody" is making the connection.  Which is OK because I set the `usershare_acl` to Everyone.  "nobody" works for the `/home/usr/Documents` and `/home/ian/Downloads` but not for the `/media/ian/UbuntuD`.  It seems to me that the `/media/ian/`... is the problem.

Can someone help me with what I need to do to make this work?  Thanks in advance.

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this just a weird coincidence or did I answer your question in the ubuntu forum: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2372142

Comment: Yes ... You did answer my question.  Thanks.  I posted the question here first but got no reply... and then tried ubuntu forums to see if I'd get some response.... which I did.